# Java open browser process causes 30 seconds delay

Tags: java, windows, process, cmd

Sometimes I have a problem opening URL in default browser from Java code:

Basically Java executes new process, but browser opens exactly after 30 seconds (seems like there is some timeout in browser opening process).

I tried both

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://google.com");
```

And

```
URI uri = new URI("http://google.com");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

Both of these calls waits 30 seconds and after that opens browser

I have found this approach (invoking start through cmd.exe) at the bottom of [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/557)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
stdin.println("start \"\" \"http://google.com\"");
stdin.close();
int returnCode = p.waitFor();
```

But it waits the same 30 seconds before opening default browser.

How to make it open instantly all the time? What am I missing about this delay?

**EDT:** Delay affects only first time browser is called from java application. (Invoking code from Swing ActionListener on button press)

Comment: How long does it take to open the browser normally?

Comment: It opens in 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
  Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

Comment: I have tried `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` it executes instantly and returns true all the time.